# Meaning of "the are" and "form" in preface of Mortimer Adler's book

Tags: meaning, grammar, meaning-in-context

In the preface of Mortimer Adler's *How to read a book*, he said:

> **The are** of reading analytically, interpretively, and critically is indispensable only for the kind of reading by which the mind passes **form** a state of understanding less to a state of understanding more...

I'm wondering if it's just a typo or *The are* and *form* actually make sense.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a one-time OCR transcription error, the moral equivalent of a typo, which is something that will never help future visitors to this site.

Comment: @tchrist Too bad. *The **are** of reading* seems so wonderfully, er *present*.

Comment: Uh… it might strictly be off topic and please, how was your response more useful than Jasper's answer?

Answer (score 3):

> The **art** of reading analytically, interpretively, and critically is
>   indispensable only for the kind of reading by which the mind passes
>   **from** a state of understanding less to a state of understanding more

is how it should read. These are typos or errors in optical recognition software.

Comment: So,  R. Wyles, can you tell us whether he found these in a paper copy of the book.  Or merely in some scanned+OCR version...

Comment: http://www.evergladeshs.org/ourpages/auto/2015/5/28/58122395/Adler%20Mortimer%20-%20How%20To%20Read%20A%20Book.pdf　I have just checked it and it is "are".

Comment: @Grizzly - It's pretty likely that that version was OCRed from the original 1940 version.